# PostgreSQL: How to do a select query on a json column that contains array or arrays

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

If I run the following query:

```
select headers from database_name.schema_name.table;
```

The output is a JSON array like this:

[image]

How do I query PostgreSQL 12 to return only the "From" nodes?

Expected result:

```
*From*
Me
Him
His
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using Postgres? Because `from db.all_messages.message` is invalid in Postgres

Comment: Yes, PostgreSQL 12 and sorry, it should really be the 'select headers from database_name.schema_name.table;'. I've changed the post to reflect that.

Comment: Postgres does not allow to reference a database like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unnest the array and then access the elements by index:

```
select x.h ->> 1 as "From"
from t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.headers) as x(h)
where x.h ->> 0 = 'From'
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=82aaa61cafdcda6ac0f2b09f55464da7)